# CSS transform rotate issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, timeline

Our team is building a timeline widget in ServiceNow's Service Portal and is running into some CSS issues when trying to make the timeline responsive.  We've cobbled together a timeline using Bootstrap progress bar, which is horizontal.  When a screen size decreases, we want that horizontal progress bar to become vertical.  We've accomplished this by doing `transform: rotate(-270deg)`, but it doesn't center and scale correctly and most of the timeline actually is off screen:

[image]

We've gotten around this by adding some margins, but are trying to figure out if there's a better way to do this:

```
#timeline-wrap{
  top:100px;
  position:relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #timeline-wrap{
    margin-top: 35%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
}
```

With the above CSS, this is what it looks like at a smaller screen size:

[image]

Comment: have you tried setting the `transform-origin`? like maybe `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` for the center

Comment: thanks @zgood, I didn't even know that was a property, but I gave that a shot and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
#timeline-wrap{
        position:relative;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        #timeline-wrap{
            margin-top:50vh !important;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            transform: rotate(-270deg);
            width:70vh;
        }
    }
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/a92uLxo4/)

Answer (score -2):

I also had a similar situation. It was to rotate a Report column header by 270 degree. But the "transform:rotate(270deg)" was not enough. Even though the rotation by 270 degrees was being done, most of the name part was getting truncated/trimmed off.

So I used the below query and it worked perfectly.

=""+[v_Room_Typ_Inv_Type_Col_Header]+""

This worked.

Comment: How your answer apply to the question? How it helps?